# How to change icons of specific file types on Ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: gnome

I want to change file icons of some specific file types like-  .html, .css etc.
I have tried using "File Type Editor (assogiate)" which is not working. I have also tried using "Gnome Tweak Tool" using icon themes. But that also does not worked properly (Though I can change folder icons , dash menu icons but not file icons).

Please suggest me a way so that I can change file icons properly. I have read some of the articles saying about some mime type changes. I could not get proper guide from any of those articles. If there is such a way then please write in detail.

Many Many Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget what dobey said. The simplest thing one can do is to install ubuntu theme packs. They have icons for every mime types (i.e files).

If you have any application related to KDE then you by default have installed Oxygen theme.

To use it all you have to do is install "Advanced settings" and then change theme using this program

```
You can find Oxygen theme @ /home/username/icons
```

You can get "Advanced Settings" program from Ubuntu Software Center". Search for it there. Install it and then go to "theme" section and change the theme to" Oxygen

Thats it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use icon themes, and name them accordingly per the `MIME Types` section of the `Icon Naming Specification`. For example, `text/html` would be `text-html.png` for a PNG icon in your custom theme.