# How can I use Yaru's R source icon for R source files in Ubuntu?

Tags: icons

I am running Ubuntu 19.10 and installed R version 3.6.1 from the Ubuntu repositories and RStudio 1.2.5033 from [rstudio.com](https://rstudio.com/). I know the Yaru icon set has a nice icon for R source files (below), but my R scripts are shown in the file explorer with the plain text icon. How can I get the R source icon for my R scripts?

[image]

I have seen several posts on Ask Ubuntu and other websites discussing how to associate icons with file extensions, such as

- [How do I change the icon for a particular file type?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52138/how-do-i-change-the-icon-for-a-particular-file-type)
- [How to change icons of specific file types on Ubuntu 11.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119308/how-to-change-icons-of-specific-file-types-on-ubuntu-11-10)
- [This more detailed post on Coder Wall](https://coderwall.com/p/qjda2q/create-new-mime-type-and-assign-an-icon-to-it-in-ubuntu)

However, following the steps in such tutorials (add a new mime type (with same name as the icon), update the mime database and the icon cache) have not worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When RStudio was installed, it added a file `/usr/share/mime/packages/rstudio.xml` with entries such as

```xml
  <mime-type type="text/x-r-source">
    <sub-class-of type="text/plain"/>
    <comment>R Source File</comment>
    <glob pattern="*.R"/>
    <glob pattern="*.r"/>
  </mime-type>
```

Now, the icon in question is named `text-x-r.png`. So, we can get the desired icon by editing the above entry to

```xml
  <mime-type type="text/x-r">
    <comment>R Source File</comment>
    <glob pattern="*.R"/>
    <glob pattern="*.r"/>
  </mime-type>
```

(You can edit it via, for example `sudo vim /usr/share/mime/packages/rstudio.xml`).

Then you just run the following commands in the terminal:

```
sudo update-mime-database /usr/share/mime
sudo gtk-update-icon-cache
```

(and refresh the file explorer if it's open). Then voila!:

[image]

Comment: Very nice! Do not hesitate to accept your own answer!

Comment: @vanadium Thanks! I will when the 2 day waiting period on that is over, unless someone comes along with a better solution or more detailed explanation or something